# javascript construct an object from an array of strings

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have the following array

```
var testArray = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
```

and an `obj` which has other object in it

```
var obj.test1.test2.test3 = "test";
```

I want to foreach the testArray

and get the following

```
obj[testArray[0]][testArray[1]][testArray[2]]
```

or `obj["test1"]["test2"]["test3"]`

which is equal to `obj.test1.test2.test3` and will return "test"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated you are aware, we can take advantage of the `obj["test1"]` notation to nest ourselves deeper into the target object.  In this case, on each iteration we re-assign the "top" of what we are pointing to to be the child of the last iteration.

```
var obj = { test1: { test2: {test3: 'test' }}};
var current = obj;

var arr = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(current === undefined){ break; }
    current = current[arr[i]];
}

console.log(current);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var testArray = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
var value = [obj].concat(testArray).reduce(function(prev, curr) {
     return prev[curr];
});
```

But remember that `reduce` is not supported by IE <= 8 ([Reduce reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)).

Answer (score 0):

```
function extractDeep(obj, propPathArr) {
   var prop = obj;
   propPathArr.forEach(function (item) {
      prop = prop[item];
   });
   return prop;
}
```

call like:

```
alert(extractDeep({a: {b: {c: "The property!"}}}, ['a', 'b', 'c']));
```

NOTE:

- **You really should add some error checking.**
- **`forEach` does not work in all browsers**

[jsFiddle can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/Yb3PE/)